# How to change the function called by a dynamically created button?

Tags: javascript, function, button, input

I was making a little game in JavaScript when I ran into a problem. In this game I create a hundred buttons using a for() loop. Eventually I want every button to call a function called 'click' and send it an int so it knows what button is pressed. So for instance when button four is pressed click(4) is called. First I tried this:

```
object.onclick = "click(4)";
```

That obviously didn't work so i searched the interwebs and fount an answer to this question on your site.

```
object.onclick = function() {click("4");}
```

I tried that (with and without the ';' at the end) but it doesn't seem work.

A more complete overview of the dummy code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   document.getElementById('myContainer').innerHTML += '<input id="tmp" type="button" value="button">';
   documengetElementById('tmp').onclick = function() {tmpFunc("bla");}

function tmpFunc(vari){
   alert(vari);
}

</script>
```

**The element myContainer is 100% empty!**

Remember, this is just dummy code to try it out. I could do this waaaaay easier but I tried to simplify it first so you don't have to look at my messy code.

**So what is the best way to call a function from a button you have created in a for loop?** If you know a way to do it totally different from the one I use just post it, I don't care how it gets solved! Although I'd also like somebody to explain why this isn't working.

Hope I didn't ask a question already answered, as far as I know I'm using the solution given for this problem in another post.

**------------UPDATE-------------**

Changed it a bit after getting an answer from somebody. This is the current code, select() isn't executed when a button is pressed. Here's the complete JavaScript code so you can copy-paste it if you want to play around with it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function addButtons(){

    var disabled = false;

    for(var i = 1; i <= 100; i++){

        currentButton = '<input id="tmp" type="button" onclick="select(\''+i+'\')">'
        document.getElementById('myContainer').innerHTML += currentButton;
        document.getElementById('tmp').id = 'btn'+i;
        gb(i).disabled = disabled;
        gb(i).style.width = "60px";
        gb(i).style.height = "60px";
        gb(i).style.fontSize = "25pt";

        function alerts(nr){
            alert("test");
        }

        if(i%10 == 0){
            document.getElementById('myContainer').innerHTML = document.getElementById('myContainer').innerHTML + '<br />';
        }else{
            if(disabled){
                disabled = false;
            }else{
                disabled = true;
            }
        }

        if(i == 60){
            gb(i).value = 'O';
            gb(i).style.color = "blue";
        }

        if(((i-1)%10 == 0) && !(gb(i).disabled)){
            gb(i).value = 'X';
            gb(i).style.color = "red";
        }
    }
}

function select(nr){
    alert("Bla!"+nr);
    gb(nr).style.height = "100px";
}

function gb(ButtonNrVanHetButton){
    return document.getElementById('btn'+ButtonNrVanHetButton);
}

addButtons();

</script>
```

Most parts aren't very interesting for solving the problem (style etc) It's supposed to look like a checkerboard.

**------------UPDATE-------------**

**Solved!** Don't use functions the javascript library already uses for other stuff like: 'select()'. Thx to everybody who tried to help!

Comment: documengetElementById('tmp').onclick ?? i believe you missed t and a .

Comment: Besides the misspelling cited above, you need to enclose the code into a function that should be called on the <body onload="">, otherwise you can't know for sure that the DOM has been loaded properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looping to create the buttons, why don't you add an onclick to the button?

for instance

```
<script>
// your function
function tmpFunc(vari)
{
   alert(vari);
}
// end your function


// define xBUTTONS
xBUTTONS = '';
for (i=0; i<100; i++)
{
    // loop buttons
    xBUTTONS += '<input id="tmp" type="button" value="button" onclick="tmpFunc(\''+i+'\')">';
}

// insert buttons into myContainer
document.getElementById('myContainer').innerHTML = xBUTTONS;
</script>
```

Comment: Well I didn't look at it like that, that's an easy way to solve it I gues! Problem is, it won't work >.< Why? I don't know. I'm updateing the post atm.

Comment: you should stay away from making functions with names which are already assigned, select is already in the JS library, change it to something like `xselect` or `btnselect` and then it will work

Answer (score 3):

first off, always attach events by using `addEventListener`. second, if you add an id to the button you dynamicly generate you can do something like this;

```
function click(){
    alert(this.id+" clicked");
}
var but;
for (var i=0,e=100,i<e;++i){
    but=document.createElement("input");
    but.id=i;
    ...//make it into your button
    but.addEventListener("click", click, false);
    document.body.appendChild(but);
}
```

Comment: Click needs an int, how do i for instance trigger click(4) with a button click. But don't mind, someone else answered my question.

Comment: you don't need to pass the int, because the click function is aware of the context(the button) you clicked on. Inside the click function you can access it by using `this`